# Not showing multiple messagebox using ctypes on python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, ctypes, messagebox

Hi I have a simple code showing a message box using ctypes
but my problem is its not appending or overlapping of messagebox after i've add MB_TOPMOST?

```
def msgbox(self,msg):
        MB_OK = 0x0
        MB_OKCXL = 0x01
        MB_YESNOCXL = 0x03
        MB_YESNO = 0x04
        MB_HELP = 0x4000
        ICON_EXLAIM=0x30
        ICON_INFO = 0x40
        ICON_STOP = 0x10
        MB_TOPMOST=0x40000
        """
                HEX VALUE LINK
        https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm
        """
        writeLogs = WriteLogs(
                    pathLog = app_config['path_logs'] +"\\"+strftime("%Y_%m_%d")+".log",
                    timedate = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                    )
        writeLogs.appendLogA(msg)
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, msg+str(operatorMessage), "[Error]", MB_OK | ICON_STOP | MB_TOPMOST)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to change the MB_TOPMOST into MB_SYSTEMMODAL and my desired output with topmost and overlapping message error boxes.

you can refer to this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and also this post on stackoverflow gives me an idea:
[Have Win32 MessageBox appear over other programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765324/have-win32-messagebox-appear-over-other-programs)

```
def msgbox(self,msg):
        MB_OK = 0x0
        MB_OKCXL = 0x01
        MB_YESNOCXL = 0x03
        MB_YESNO = 0x04
        MB_HELP = 0x4000
        ICON_EXLAIM=0x30
        ICON_INFO = 0x40
        ICON_STOP = 0x10
        MB_TOPMOST=0x40000
        MB_SYSTEMMODAL=0x1000
        """
                HEX VALUE LINK
        https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm
        """
        writeLogs = WriteLogs(
                    pathLog = app_config['path_logs'] +"\\"+strftime("%Y_%m_%d")+".log",
                    timedate = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                    )
        writeLogs.appendLogA(msg)
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, msg+str(operatorMessage), "[Error]", MB_OK | ICON_STOP | MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
```

Comment: In your class body you should set `_user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')`. Then reference `self._user32.MessageBoxA`. The problem is `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA` is shared by all modules, so any module could set the `argtypes` or `errcheck` attributes in ways that break your code.

Comment: hi sir thanks for your comment, but could you have a sample code you talk about?

Comment: `msgbox` is a method of some class, since the first argument is `self`. I suggested to define `_user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')` in the class body, as a class attribute that you can reference from the instance as `self._user32`. This will be your private copy of `ctypes.WinDLL('user32')` instead of using the shared `ctypes.windll.user32`. Note that `ctypes.windll.user32` is implemented by calling `ctypes.WinDLL('user32')`  and caching the result on the `ctypes.windll` loader. This cached instance is shared by all modules that use `ctypes.windll`, which should be avoided.

Comment: thank you for fast reply sir...I think i get what you telling about. another thing
now that the piece of code is capable of of multiple pop of messagebox when calling. Is there a way to kill/close all messageboxes generated at one time??